# Cannot write cookie

Tags: go

I'm trying to add two cookies to the web page, as below, but none of them is working:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "net/smtp"
    "strconv"
)

type verification struct {
    Email string
}

func verify(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var user verification
    err := decoder.Decode(&user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(user.Email)

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp := make(map[string]string)

    min := 1000
    max := 9999
    code := strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(max-min) + min)
    // make sure to allow less secure apps:
    // https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
    from := "myemail@gmail.com"
    pass := "mypasscode"
    to := user.Email
    body := fmt.Sprintf("Hello, your verification code is: %v", code)

    msg := "From: " + from + "\n" +
        "To: " + to + "\n" +
        "Subject: Hello there\n\n" +
        body

    err = smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587",
        smtp.PlainAuth("Cocoon Solutions", from, pass, "smtp.gmail.com"),
        from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))

    if err != nil {
        resp["Error"] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", err)
        jsonResp, err := json.Marshal(resp)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error happened in JSON marshal. Err: %s", err)
        }
        w.Write(jsonResp)
        return
    }

    log.Print("verification code sent, check your email")

    cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "email", Value: "user.Email", Path: "/"} // user.Email
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

    cookie2 := http.Cookie{Name: "VerificationCode", Value: "code", Path: "/"} // code
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie2)

    resp["VerificationCode"] = code
    jsonResp, err := json.Marshal(resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error happened in JSON marshal. Err: %s", err)
    }
    w.Write(jsonResp)
}
```

Knowing that in another code, it is working perfectly:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

type register struct {
    Company, Name, Mobile, Whatsapp, Country, City string
}

func registration(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method)                                                             //get request method
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(fmt.Sprintf("%v", "templates/registration.html"))) // index.html
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        //  t, _ := template.ParseFiles("login.gtpl")
        tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        r.ParseForm()
        fmt.Println(r.Form)
        // map[city:[Dammam] company:[Aujan] mobile:[059] name:[Hasan] whatsapp:[059]]
        // logic part of log in
        fmt.Println("company:", r.Form["company"]) // Field name at the html form
        fmt.Println("name:", r.Form["name"])
        fmt.Println("mobile:", r.Form["mobile"])
        fmt.Println("whatsapp:", r.Form["whatsapp"])
        fmt.Println("country:", r.Form["country"])
        fmt.Println("city:", r.Form["city"]) // city: [Dammam]

        //map[string]string
        content := register{
            Company:  r.PostForm.Get("company"),
            Name:     r.PostForm.Get("name"),
            Mobile:   r.PostForm.Get("mobile"),
            Whatsapp: r.PostForm.Get("whatsapp"),
            Country:  r.PostForm.Get("country"),
            City:     r.PostForm.Get("city"),
        }

        cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "logged", Value: "true", Path: "/"}
        http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

        http.Redirect(w, r, "/index", http.StatusSeeOther) // Redirect to another url
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)` writes the header, cookie is a header, so setting the cookie *after* writing the header is not-ok.

In other words, any modifications to `w.Header()` *after* `w.WriteHeader` was invoked, will not be present in the HTTP Response Header. `http.SetCookie` sets the Cookie by modifying `w.Header()`.

---

[`ResponseWriter.Header()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.2#ResponseWriter.Header)

> Changing the header map after a call to WriteHeader (or Write)
> has no effect unless the modified headers are trailers.

---

Related: [Modify http.ResponseWriter when passed as a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477901/modify-http-responsewriter-when-passed-as-a-function-argument)